# Почему не работает react компонент?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть простой react компонент но при попытке отрендерить его у меня падает ошибка синтаксиса, хотя все скобки вроде открыты и закрыты где надо:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: http://localhost:3000/js/app.js: Unexpected token (27:2)   25 |       )   26 |     }
> 27 |   };
     |   ^   28 |    29 |   render: function() {   30 |     return (
```

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться почему так происходит. Как я понимаю этот код: есть функция `getNewsData` в ней `map` заполняет массив и функция `getNewsData` должна вернуть этот массив. В чем моя ошибка объясните пожалуйста. Спасибо.

Сам компонент:

```
var News = React.createClass({

  getNewsData: function() {
    return  this.props.data.map(function(item, index) {
      return (
        <div key={index}>
          <p className="news__author">{item.author}:</p>
          <p className="news__text">{item.text}</p>
        </div>
      )
    }
  };

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="news">
        {this.getNewsData()}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var Comments = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      return (
        <div>
          comments
        </div>
      );
    }
});

var App = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        Всем привет, я компонент App!
        <Comments />
        <News data={my_news}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: У `getNewsData` в конце должна быть запятая, а не точка с запятой и в конце первого `return` надо добавить `)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подключи  `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.24/browser.js"></script>` в `index.html`

и добавить `type="text/babel"` в

`<script type="text/babel" src="js/app.js"></script>`